# how to check Android OS really uses Multiple cores

Tags: android

We all know Android OS supports multiple core architecture . But how to test the threads are actually  getting processed on multiple cores ?Its a project assignment . Please suggest how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this.Might help you

private int getNumCores() {
    //Private Class to display only CPU devices in the directory listing
    class CpuFilter implements FileFilter {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            //Check if filename is "cpu", followed by a single digit number
            if(Pattern.matches("cpu[0-9]+", pathname.getName())) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }      
    }

    try {
        //Get directory containing CPU info
        File dir = new File("/sys/devices/system/cpu/");
        //Filter to only list the devices we care about
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(new CpuFilter());
        //Return the number of cores (virtual CPU devices)
        return files.length;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //Default to return 1 core
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [parsing /proc/cpuinfo](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-get-number-of-cpus-core-command/), for example using [Guava's Files helper](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) to read the file:

```
public int numCores() throws IOException {
    Pattern processorLinePattern = Pattern.compile("^processor\\s+: \\d+$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    String cpuinfo = Files.toString(new File("/proc/cpuinfo"), Charsets.US_ASCII);
    Matcher matcher = processorLinePattern.matcher(cpuinfo);
    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

You should generally prefer doing I/O with helper libraries like Guava or Apache Commons, there are many edge cases to get right. If you need to avoid the dependency, implement something similar yourself (there are several holes in this sample implementation, but it's not too terrible):

```
private String readFile(File file, Charset charset) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charset));
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return result.toString();
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
}

public int numCores() throws IOException {
    // ...
    String cpuinfo = readFile(new File("/proc/cpuinfo"), Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    // ...
}
```